# Binomial identity involving central binomial coefficient

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I came across this nice binomial identity

$${‎‎\sum}_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^k {2n \choose k} {2k \choose k}}{n+k \choose k} = 1$$

This is equivalent to the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1(-2n, 1/2; n+1; 4)$. I am having a hard time trying to prove this. Can someone help me with a hint to prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F(n,k)=(-1)^k\binom{2n}k\binom{2k}{k}\big/\binom{n+k}{k}$ be the summand, and let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}F(n,k)$ be the sum to be computed. Let
$$
G(n,k)=(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k-2}\binom{2k}{k}\Big/\binom{n+k}{k}.
$$
You can show, through tedious algebraic manipulations alone, that for all $n,k\ge 0$,
$$
3(F(n,k)-F(n+1,k))=G(n,k+1)-G(n,k).\tag{*}
$$
Specifically, write both sides in terms of factorials, then cancel common factorial terms until all that remains is a rational equation in $n,k$, which can be proven by clearing denominators and polynomial manipulation.

Summing both sides of $(*)$ from $k=0$ to $2n+2$, you get that
$$
3S_{n}-3S_{n+1}=G(n,2n+3)-G(n,0)=0-0=0.
$$
This proves that $S_{n}$ is independent of $n$, so you need only verify that $S_0=1$ to prove $S_n=1$ for all $n$.

---

If you are wondering where $G(n,k)$ came from, it is of the form $G(n,k)=F(n,k)\cdot R(n,k),$ where $$R(n,k)=k(k-1)/(2n-k+1)(2n-k+2),$$ after canceling some common factors, necessary to prevent division by zero. This function $R(n,k)$ which causes $(*)$ to be satisfied can be found using Zeilberger's algorithm. For example, in Maxima, you can use the commands

```
load(zeilberger)$ 
Zeilberger((-1)^k * binomial(2*n, k) * binomial(2*k, k) / binomial(n + k, k), k, n);
```

to get both the coefficients $[3,-3]$ on the LHS of $(*)$, and $R(n,k)$. You can see for yourself by copy pasting those commands into this [online Maxima compiler](http://maxima.cesga.es/index.php?c=scu0jkhx2gbo4egcnhatv&n=9).

My purpose in including this explanation is to help spread the word that **a proof of "any" summation identity  with binomial coefficients can be found automatically with the right computer program.** For anyone who encounters complicated binomial summations like this a lot, this power is very desirable! In fact, if you only have the summation, you can determine if a closed form exists using the same algorithm. The exact requirements on the "any" part  are described in the book $A = B$, available for free online: [A = B on Herbert Wilf's website](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html). This is a must-read for anyone who wants this power.

Comment: Does it work only for hypergeometric identities?

Comment: Yes; if the hypergeometric series has a closed form as a single hypergeometric term, this algorithm finds it. If not, it at least finds a recurrence with polynomial coefficients that the sum satisfies. Read A = B!

Comment: I just have tried without success to apply it to this similarly looking [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3685753), which was solved by telescoping.

Comment: @user The Zeilberger method works best when the hypergeometric term $F(n,k)$ vanishes for $k$ outside of a compact interval (which can depend on $n$). This was not the case for your other summation. However, things happened to work out nicely. In your case, it would have been actually cleaner to use Gosper's algorithm, which finds an antidifference if it exists.

Answer (score 5):

In trying to verify the identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k
{n+k\choose k}^{-1} {2n\choose k} {2k\choose k} = 1$$

we see that

$${n+k\choose k}^{-1} {2n\choose k}
= \frac{(2n)! / (2n-k)!}{(n+k)! / n!}
= {3n\choose n}^{-1} {3n\choose 2n-k}$$

so that we seek to prove

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k {3n\choose 2n-k} {2k\choose k}
= {3n\choose n}.$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k {3n\choose k}
{4n-2k\choose 2n-k}
= [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{4n}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n} (-1)^k {3n\choose k}
\frac{z^k}{(1+z)^{2k}}$$

Here the coefficient extractor enforces the range of the sum and we
find

$$[z^{2n}] (1+z)^{4n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k {3n\choose k}
\frac{z^k}{(1+z)^{2k}}
= [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{4n}
\left(1-\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}\right)^{3n}
\\ = [z^{2n}] \frac{1}{(1+z)^{2n}}
(1+z+z^2)^{3n}.$$

Expanding the second powered term

$$[z^{2n}] \frac{1}{(1+z)^{2n}}
\sum_{q=0}^{3n} {3n\choose q} (1+z)^{3n-q} z^{2q}$$

The coefficient extractor sets the upper limit of the sum to $n$ and we
get (note that the powers of $1+z$ do not have a pole at zero hence the
expansion about zero starts with $z^{2q}$ and there is no  contribution
to $[z^{2n}]$ when $q\gt n$):

$$[z^{2n}] \sum_{q=0}^{n} {3n\choose q} (1+z)^{n-q} z^{2q}
= \sum_{q=0}^{n} {3n\choose q}
{n-q\choose 2n-2q} = {3n\choose n}.$$

Observe that the the power $n-q$ to which $1+z$ is raised is a
non-negative integer and hence we are justified  in writing $[z^{2n}]
z^{2q} (1+z)^{n-q} = [z^{2n-2q}] (1+z)^{n-q} = {n-q\choose 2n-2q}.$  The
only $q$ in the range $0\le q\le n$ where this binomial coefficient  is
not zero is $q=n$, producing a contribution of ${3n\choose n}$ and we
have the claim.

Comment: I don't know how you thought to bring $(3n)!$ into the picture, is that a standard trick? Or something you just came up with?

Comment: Re-factorizations of ${p\choose q} {q\choose r}$ and ${p\choose r} / {q\choose r}$ have appeared at MSE many times, I'm not sure if there is a name, I think there might be.